# Varnish returns incorrect backend content from User-Agent rule

Tags: varnish

I have a simple rule to redirect traffic to special backend if the User-Agent == GlobalSign or if the request url is /globalsign. I have noticed on a rare occasion varnish will return content from the special backend incorrectly. It seems happens randomly and does not repeat.

```
if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)GlobalSign" ||  req.url ~ "^/globalsign" ) {
    set req.url = "/";
    set req.backend = dgs1;
    return(pipe);
}
```

Backend rules

```
    backend b1 {
     //Backend 1
    .host = "10.8.8.16";
    .port = "80";
    .probe = {
        .url = "/service_up";
        .timeout = 1s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 8;
    }
}


backend gs1 {
         // Set host: Globalsign 
        .host = "10.8.8.15";
        .port = "80";
        .probe = {
            .url = "/service_up";
            .timeout = 5s;
            .interval = 5s;
            .window = 10;
            .threshold = 8;
        }
    }

director dgs1 random {

  {
        .backend =   gs1;
        .weight  = 1;
    }

}

director d01 random {
      {
        .backend =   b1;
        .weight  = 1;
    }
}
```

Full VCL

```
include "backends.vcl";
include "bans.vcl";
include "acl.vcl";

sub vcl_recv {

    // Use the director we set up above to answer the request if it's not cached.
    set req.backend = d01;
    if( req.url ~ "^/service_up" ) {
        return(lookup);
    }

    if(client.ip ~ evil_networks){
        error 403 "Forbidden";
    }

    if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)GlobalSign" ||  req.url ~ "^/globalsign" ) {
        set req.url = "/";
        set req.backend = dgs1;
        return(pipe);
    }

    return(pass)
}

sub vcl_fetch {
    set beresp.grace = 24h;

    if (beresp.status >= 400) {
         return (hit_for_pass);
    }

    // New Set Longer Cache
    if (req.http.user-agent ~ "(Googlebot|msnbot|Yandex|Slurp|Bot|Crawl|bot|Baid|Mediapartners-Google)") {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        set beresp.ttl = 5d;
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (req.request == "GET" && req.url ~ "\.(css|xml|txt)$") {
        set beresp.ttl = 5d;
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        return (deliver);
    }
    // multimedia
    if (req.request == "GET" && req.url ~ "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png|tiff|tif|ico|img|tga|woff|eot|ttf|svg|wmf|js|swf|ico)$") {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        set beresp.ttl = 5d;
        return (deliver);
    }
    set beresp.ttl = 5d;
    return (deliver);
}

include "errors.vcl";

sub vcl_deliver {

    return(deliver);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what "incorrectly" means in this case?

Comment: Only traffic with User-Agent containing GlobalSign or req.url ~ "^/globalsign" shoudl use director dgs1.    However users that do not meet that criteria are receiving content that would only come from dgs1

Answer (score 0):

I guess **return(pipe);** is the suspect one.

If you have keep-alive HTTP client making just one request with *GlobalSign* user agent or to */globalsign* url, all subsequent requests will be piped to *dgs1*, even if they do not meet the criteria.

Try to avoid piping if possible, it's common source of a lot of hard to track issues. And possibly security hole too.